# In revealing module pattern, can you make public a hash property?

Tags: javascript

So I have a standard revealing module pattern and rather than make public *all* my config settings, I just want to make public a smaller subset of those configs. It isn't working and curious if there is a workaround or something I am missing.

```
   var rmp = function(){
       var config = {
           someValue = "I like p&j sandwiches",
           anotherVal = {
              a: 'somevalue'
           }
       }

       var func1 = function(){
          // do some stuff

       }

       return {
           func1: func1,
           config.someValue: someValue // <-- doesn't work
           config[someValue] : someValue // <-- doesn't work
           config : config // <-- works
       }

   }
```

Seems to not allow properties of the hash to be available as stand alone.
now, of course, if I create a func that just returns that value, yeah then it works. But I don't want to create another func for this.

```
      var showme = function(){
         return config.someValue;
      }


       return {
           func1: func1,
           showme: showme
       }
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax. You need to create the proper structure in the returned object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
return {
       func1: func1,
       someValue: config.someValue
}
```

Now your `config` object is not exposed to the public, except its `someValue` property.

**Explanation**

Here are your problems. First you have syntax error in your code. You're missing a `comma` after both `config.someValue: someValue` and `config[someValue] : someValue`.

Second, for example in `config.someValue: someValue` you're referring to `someValue` - on the right side - which is not defined in your script. The correct way is `config.someValue` not `someValue` alone.

Third thing is that I think you have a bit of misunderstanding about how both javascript objects and also revealing module design pattern work. When you're writing the `return` part, you do NOT need to use the property names to expose them to the public. For example you can write `whateverFunc: func1` and it's gonna work perfectly fine. What you're trying to do there is to use for example `config.someValue` and `config[someValue]`, which could work but doesn't have any relation/access to your actual `config` object.

To make it more clear imagine the following `return` object:

```
return {
    doSomething: func1,
    doAnotherThing: function () {
        return config.someValue;
    },
    getSomeValue: config.anotherVal
}
```

So, as you can see the object properties - left side - are just a name to reveal the value that has assigned to them - right side.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make some properties of an object private and some public. What you can do however is define a new object that exposes the properties you want public and return that. For the best effect, the public object's properties will change the actual config object, like in the following example:

```
var rmp = function(){
  var config = {
    someValue : "I like p&j sandwiches",
    anotherVal : {
      a: 'somevalue'
    }
  };

  var publicConfig = Object.create(null, {
    someValue : {
      set : function(val) { config.someValue = val; },
      get : function() { return config.someValue; }
    }
  });

  var func1 = function(){
    console.log(config.someValue);
  };

  return {
    func1: func1,
    config: publicConfig
  };
};


var r = new rmp();
r.func1(); // I like p&j sandwiches
r.config.someValue = 'Changed';
r.func1(); // Changed
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/iJEZaBu/1/edit

Comment: Well, actually you CAN make some properties of an object private and some others public, however you can NOT change a property of an-already-public object to private.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the subproperties of config like that. This should work for you

```
var rmp = function(){
   var config = {
       someValue = "I like p&j sandwiches",
       anotherVal = {
          a: 'somevalue'
       }
   }

   var func1 = function(){
      // do some stuff

   }

   return {
       func1: func1,
       config: { someValue: config.someValue},
   }
```

}

This way, you are effectively copying the selected properties of your closure's config to a different config in the return object.